# How to submit photo upload when clicking "open" in file browser

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right now I have it as when a user clicks on the image the file browser will open up. But what I want is for after the file browser has opened and a file is chosen, once you click "open" the form will submit and the image will upload.

This is the closest I have gotten using the answer chosen here: [Open File Browser on Link Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687660/open-file-browser-on-link-click)

code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <img height="120" width="140" id="profileImage" alt="profile-image" class="userimg" style="margin-bottom: 1rem;" onclick="document.getElementById('imageFile').click();" src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" />
</div>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?id=<?php echo $childId; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageForm" name="imageForm" class="text-center">
  <!--  <input type="submit" id="btn-imageUpload" value="Submit" name="submit" /> -->
    <input type="file"  style="display:none;" id="imageFile" name="profile-photo" onchange="this.form.submit() enctype=”multipart/form-data” capture/>
</form>
```

It almost worked.. When I click "open" in the file browser the page submits and refreshes, but the photo was not uploaded at all.

But it works fine if I submit using the "submit" button on the page instead of the "open" button in the file browser.

Comment: Your code has "smart" quotes `”` and invalid HTML... is it actually like that in your real code?

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie still learning. But thanks!

Comment: Being new is fine, but can you answer whether or not those types of quotes are in your code?  If they are, replace them with regular quote marks.  Also, you can validate your code here:  https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input  That will help you resolve issues like this.

Comment: They are, as this is the way I have learned to do it and have seen it this way in other code as well. Thank you for letting me know and thanks so much for the link! Very helpful, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, those curly quotes can do a number on code and fail outright in serverside executed code and JS; HTML might be a different thing and some browsers might accept those. If those were actually part of your code, then IMHO, the answer you accepted didn't address everything, so that for me is only a partial answer. Edit: So do as @Brad said and visit that site to validate what you're using now. I think you'll find that it might not pass with flying colors.

Comment: Will do! Thanks guys for the feedback =]

Comment: @TaahiraCarter Whomever told you to use smart quotes is wrong.  Wherever you've copied/pasted them from is incorrect.  It's not uncommon for some blog platform (i.e. Wordpress) to try to auto-convert code to some style, essentially infecting it with smart quotes.  Just to be clear, double quotes `"` are fine and correct, it's the curly style `”` that are incorrect.

Comment: Ahh now I see, thanks for clearing that up. My code is all double quotes. I didn’t even notice the “smart quotes”. I am going to look through my code again and see if there are more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener to your file input. Once it recognizes a change you can send them to where they need to go. Or make the request via AJAX.

```js
var form = document.querySelector('#profile_image'),
      input = document.querySelector('input[name="picture"]');

input.addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // form.submit(); // Uncomment this line or change it to your preferred AJAX mechanism
  document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += 'Event Listener worked!';
});
```

```html
<form action="/upload/profile/<?=$childId?>" method="POST" id="profile_image">

  <input type="file" name="picture" />

</form>
```

This should easily submit your form.

Comment: -1 for this FileReader stuff... it's totally irrelevant to the question and will lead people astray.  There is no reason for it.

Comment: @Brad i see what you are saying... I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TaahiraCarter no problem